# Spamassassin: store bayes per user in mysql (with amavis)

Tags: mysql, postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I use postfix (mysql virtual users) + amavis + spamassassin and configured spamassassin to use mysql for storing the bayes data:

```
use_bayes                       1
bayes_auto_learn                1

bayes_store_module              Mail::SpamAssassin::BayesStore::MySQL
bayes_sql_dsn                   DBI:mysql:<db>:localhost
bayes_sql_username              <user>
bayes_sql_password              <password>
```

In the mysql table "bayes_vars" I found only a row with the username "amavis".

Is it possible for spamassassin to use the e-mail address as username instead "amavis" for each mail?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use sa_username_maps to split it up.